# Eclipse plugin for c/c++ call graph generator not working properly

Tags: c++, c, windows, call-graph

I have installed eclipse plugin for call graph generator using the following link.
http://certiv.net/updates/

That plugin has been successfuly installed as I can checked that from installed plugins in eclipse.
Now problem is still I am unable to view option op generating call graph under project explorer->right click on the project whose call graph u want to create-> profile as-> call graph

as shown in the following link.
This link is for linux but i have installed this plugin on windows platform.
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/Callgraph/User_Guide

Can anybody help me how do i need to configure eclipse for generation of call graphs. I am using eclipse galileo.

Answer (score 0):

According to the user guide Callgraph is using [SystemTap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap), which is absolutely linux specific and thus it will never work on windows (at least as long as only SystemTap is the only supported way to retrieve information).